# Where should I put miscellaneous shell commands in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I use `zsh` with `Oh My Zsh` for easy theme configuration.

Where should I put miscellaneous commands, like `brew` and auto-completion?

```
if [[ -x "/opt/homebrew/bin/brew" ]]; then
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
fi

if type brew &>/dev/null; then
    FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-completions:$FPATH

    autoload -Uz compinit
    compinit
fi

source <(kubectl completion zsh)
```

I thought of using `~/.zprofile`, but it's sourced before `~/.zshrc`, and so `source <(kubectl completion zsh)` doesn't work (why?).

Comment: Everything shown is only relevant to an interactive shell (and further, is probably not doing anything that would be inherited by a subshell), so I would say it *should* be in `.zshrc` and not `.zprofile`.

Comment: So, you would edit the `~/.zshrc` generated by Oh My Zsh?

Comment: Aren't exports inherited by a subshell?

Comment: There is no subshell involved in your question, and I certainly would not want any tool to **generate** my `.zshrc`. This is a file where I place my definitions in the way I want, and I don't want other programs to interfer here. If oh-my-zsh (I don't use this software, so I can't know) insists in generating a definition file, I hope that they allow you to specify the filename which is generated by it. Choose a suitable name (for instance `.oh_my.rc` and source this from your .zshrc.

Comment: Exports are, but the completion system is based on functions, which cannot be exported.